# How to implement the transition through the pages of the site without breaking the music using AJAX?

Tags: ajax

How could i implement the transition through the pages of the site without breaking the music using AJAX?

**1.** Turn on the music in the "https://example.com/music" 
**2.** The music is playing 
**3.** Go to another page (For example, "https://example.com/feed") 
**4.** The music is still playing

Comment: Could you show us something you have already tried?

Comment: I didn't try anything bcz i don't know how to do that at all. Sorry for disappointment

Comment: You should research before asking here.

Comment: Make the music player dynamic and add it to the global scope of your file, example the header section or script section that is shared across your project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do that you should make `Single Page Application`.

To make `Single Page Application` use `Vue`, `Angular` or `React`.

I recommend you to use `Vue`.